# the markup in the document following the root element must be well formed,error parsing xml not well formed (invalid token)

Tags: android, xml, android-activity

when i try to run my app it keeps giving me the same message above

```
<EditText android:id="@+id/edit_message"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:layout_width=`"0dp"`
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:hint="@string/edit_message"/>
```

I tried putting android:id under  but it still gave me the same message.
im making this app for a competition, please repond as soon as you can its in 5 days.
the `s is the stackoverflow code thing

Comment: post your layout completely

Comment: stackoverflow messed up my question.i'll just make it easier to understand when i use eclispe in activity_main.xml and when i try to run the app a red x is next to <EditText saying the problem above. the `s is the stackoverflow code thing

Answer (score 1):

I just copy pasted your code and the error is where you have the line android:layout_width=`"0dp"` - you have single quotes here surrounding the value. Take them out.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `s (single quotes) in this line:

```
android:layout_width=`"0dp"`
```

It should be

```
android:layout_width="0dp"
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is the only element in your layout file then android name space is missing. try following:

```
<EditText xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/edit_message"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:hint="@string/edit_message"/>
```

And as other people are pointing, remove apostrophes surrounding the weight value.